# Error: vector does not name a type

Tags: c++

I'm having lots of errors in my final project (a poker and black jack sim). I'm using a vector to implement the "hands" in the blackJack class, and I'm using a structured data type declared in another class, which is publicly inherited. The error I'm worried about is the compiler I'm using telling me that I'm not declaring a type in the vector.

blackJack header file:

```
 #ifndef BLACKJACK_H
 #define BLACKJACK_H
 #include <vector>
 #include "card.h"

 class blackJack: public cards
 {
 private:
    vector <Acard> playerHand;
    vector <Acard> dealerHand;

 public:
    blackJack();
    void dealHands();
    void hitOrStay();
    void dealerHit();
    int handleReward(int);
    void printHands();
 };
 #endif
```

card header file (this is the class black jack inherits from):

```
 #ifndef CARD_H
 #define CARD_H

 const char club[] = "\xe2\x99\xa3";
 const char heart[] = "\xe2\x99\xa5";
 const char spade[] = "\xe2\x99\xa0";
 const char diamond[] = "\xe2\x99\xa6";
 //structured data to hold card information
 //including:
 // a number, representing Ace-King (aces low)
 //a character, representing the card's suit
 struct Acard
 {
   int number;
   char pic[4];
 };



 // a class to hold information regarding a deck of cards
 //including:
 //An array of 52 Acard datatypes, representing our Deck
 //an index to the next card in the array
 //a constructor initializing the array indices to Ace-king in each suit
 //a function using random numbers to shuffle our deck of cards
 //13 void functions to print each card
 class cards
 {
  private:
    Acard Deck[52];
    int NextCard;
  public:
    cards();
    Acard getCard();
    void shuffleDeck();
    void cardAce(char[]);
    void cardTwo(char[]);
    void cardThree(char[]);
    void cardFour(char[]);
    void cardFive(char[]);
    void cardSix(char[]);
    void cardSeven(char[]);
    void cardEight(char[]);
    void cardNine(char[]);
    void cardTen(char[]);
    void cardJack(char[]);
    void cardQueen(char[]);
    void cardKing(char[]);

 };

 #endif
```

Answer (score 83):

You forgot to add `std::` namespace prefix to `vector` class name.

Answer (score 24):

use:

```
std::vector <Acard> playerHand;
```

everywhere qualify it by `std::`

or do:

```
using std::vector;
```

in your cpp file.

You have to do this because `vector` is defined in the `std` namespace and you do not tell your program to find it in `std` namespace, you need to tell that.

Answer (score 18):

Also you can add **`#include<vector>`** in the header. When two of the above solutions don't work.

Comment: For some reason vector only works when included in my header file. If I put it in my source file it doesn't work and it's the only one that works this way. Why?

Comment: That shouldn't do anything because there are no vectors in the card header file...

Answer (score 15):

You need to either qualify `vector` with its namespace (which is `std`), or import the namespace at the top of your CPP file:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: U can do this but only in source files. Not in headers because then U will a very bad thing (I mean some spaghetti).

Comment: @LokiAstari why not do this? Isn't this what 'using namespace' is for?  or is the issue with flooding your namespace with everything from std? (I'm not arguing, I'm learning c++)

Comment: @jk. This discussion isn't related to the question, so I'll keep it to a minimum, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) explains it quite well.